# Creating a character alias in sas, more than 3 words

Tags: sql, sas

I tried to give some of my columns long aliases ( eg. ‘If denied , then give reason’

```
Proc sql;
Create table xxx as
Sélect 
First name,
Lastsame,
Status as ‘If denied, then give reason’;
QuiT;
```

I tried the above and got error :
‘Syntax error, expecting a name’ below ‘as’

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues with this, and you have two ways to solve it.

*First*, your column alias is a string, not a name.  SAS (and most any SQL implementation) expects a *name* - so this:

```
select status as reason
```

Not this:

```
select status as 'reason'
```

However, if you remove the quotes, that won't work because of the spaces - hence your *second* issue.  You can fix that by adding an `n` after the quotes - that turns it from a string into a name literal.

```
select status as 'If denied, then give reason'n
```

*Third*, you may not have the ability to use names like this by default, depending on your value of `option validvarname`.  You need to set it to `any` in order to allow names like this, otherwise only names with no spaces are legal.

```
options validvarname=any;
```

In total, what this will look like is:

```
option validvarname=any;
Proc sql;
  Create table xxx as
    Select 
      Firstname,
      Lastname,
      Status as ‘If denied, then give reason’n;
Quit;
```

---

One thing you may want to consider, though, is the concept of `label`.  A label is sort of what you're talking about here - some text to explain a variable - without actually having to use a weird and hard to work with variable name.

```
Proc sql;
  Create table xxx as
    Select 
      Firstname,
      Lastname,
      Status  ‘If denied, then give reason’;
Quit;
```

Leaving out the `as` is all you need - then the label is there. The label will be attached to the variable, and if you `proc print` with the `label` option it will print the label instead of the variable name. You still can use the `status` variable name in code (where it's readable) but the label is attached to the data and easy to use as documentation and for understanding.

Alternately, use underscores (if_denied_then_give_reason); but personally I find `status` a better variable name and `if denied then give reason` a good label. This is how we, for example, format our datasets from surveys where I work - the question text becomes the label, and the variable name is a shorter, easy to work with, but still meaningful name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a 'n' to the end of the column name:

```
Status as ‘If denied, then give reason’n;
```